# Does Civi rename picture files?

Tags: contacts, custom-fields, webform-civicrm

I have a situation where authorized users can upload a scan of their passports.  While this doesn't happen often, there are times where various users will upload "Passport.jpg" as necessary.  While the upload seems to work, it appears as if we come across an issue that when we go back to look at the picture, the wrong picture is referenced.  Only the "Passport.jpg" that came from the first user will show up.  My initial thinking is that somewhere between the Civi and picture storage collection, the query looks for the name of the file rather than some other identifying field.  Is my suspicions accurate?  If so, how do I prevent this confusion from happening again?  We are using Civi 5.31.1 and Drupal 7.  The following screenshot is taken from the civicrm_file table and only showing entries where the uri field is exactly "passport.jpg".[image: Passport Image Entries]

Comment: Normally there's a hash appended. What feature/technique is being used for the upload?

Comment: We're using the standard Drupal webforms picture upload functionality. I believe that this is accomplished through the webform_civicrm module.